# I need to execute test cases in robot file in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, robotframework

As there are huge number of test cases,it takes lot of time to complete the entire execution.I am not using selenium. Is there any way that can help to achieve parallel execution in robot framework or python .Any example would be of great help.

Comment: Have you tried a simple google search before asking?

Answer (score 2):

[Pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot) is likely what you're looking for. Though you should know that this will not magically make your tests thread-safe. In other words Pabot can only help you with the execution part, but your test cases will need to be designed with parallelization in mind. For example, test cases that make changes to a database or edit a global file may not be parallelization-friendly and will need to be redesigned with parallelization in mind.

[PabotLib](https://cdn.rawgit.com/mkorpela/pabot/master/PabotLib.html) can help you design thread-safe test cases when needed.

Answer (score 0):

See pabot here : https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot

First install pabot:

```
 pip3 install -U robotframework-pabot
```

Then you can run rest under case directory in parallel as simple as:

```
pabot --testlevelsplit case
```